# Python ambiguous behavior in class program destructor crash

Tags: python

The below Python code works perfectly alright.

```
class X:
   __n = 0

   def __init__(self):
       X.__n += 1
       print "cons", X.__n

   def __del__(self):
       X.__n -= 1
       print "dest", X.__n

a = X()
b = X()
```

where as the same one with slight changes crashing in every other platform

```
class A:
   n = 0

   def __init__(self):
       A.n += 1
       print "constructor", A.n

   def __del__(self):
       A.n -= 1
       print "destructor", A.n

a1 = A() 
a2 = A()
```

```
constructor 1
constructor 2
Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'n'" in <bound method A.__del__ of <__main__.A instance at 0xfff4526c>> ignored
Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'n'" in <bound method A.__del__ of <__main__.A instance at 0xfff4528c>> ignored
```

I am not getting any clue about this dubious behaviour.

Comment: maybe related to this: https://shahriar.svbtle.com/underscores-in-python ?

Comment: Please provide more information as it is working for me. What is the error do you get?

Comment: I tried it and got the error: `Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'n'" in <bound method A.__del__ of <__main__.A instance at 0x02D44378>> ignored`

Comment: @TedKleinBergman: Which Python version?

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri Python 2.7.12.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman Mine is python 2.7.10 and i do not think it should make difference. You get this error while executing which line of code?

Comment: It seems as the class is collected by garbage collection before the object. The problem is when the program quits. I managed to surpass the error by just typing `a1 = A` at the last line for some reason.

Comment: Python 2.6.8 on my windows, Python 2.7 on my Ubuntu 12.04 Linux and also checked on Mac, in all these platforms the above code crashes with that error posted above

Comment: I also managed to surpass the error when dereferencing the object manually `del a1`. After some testing it seems that the error only occurs when the program quits. That's why @MoinuddinQuadri didn't get an error, you were running it in the console.

Comment: Fun fact: Renaming your class to P or higher alphabetically will resolve the error if you're only using 1 variable.

Comment: @IbrahimQuraish you realise that `__del__` isn't a destructor if you're thinking of it in C++/similar terms? Read carefully about [`__del__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__)